# Downloading Google activity browser history only downloads the last 8 days, how do I get more than that?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-search-history

This question [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/137491/is-there-a-way-to-restore-google-chromes-browsing-history-after-clearing-cache) is more precise and might be the answer.

How can I get all of my activity history? The only way I can access it now is by scrolling down the my activity section. This is not ideal at all and as soon as I reach two/three months ago the browser page doesn't react anymore.

A JSON file, a PDF or basically anything will be cool.

I tried a few Chrome extensions which failed to do what I wanted probably because I deleted the cache, which is also the reason why I can't use the browser history in the browser but have to use the Google my activity section.

When I try to download the file from Google's new data downloading service called [takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout), it only downloads the from the 14th of December days, perhaps because I deleted the cache then? I downloaded the `BroswerHistory` in the product `Chrome` and also tried the `Chrome` section in the product `My Activity`

UPDATE:
The [my activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) section actually collects data from apps which I mistakenly thought of as being part of the browser history because these apps are not part of google. So I actually have no access to the browser activity from before I deleted the cache is there a way to get access to that data?.

Comment: Thanks for posting here! Hope you get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/?pli=1) to export your location history, you'll get a zip file that contains all of your location history in JSON format: [image].

I have location history going back to 2012: [image]

EDIT: This question was about browsing history it seems - takeout will still work here but you're not getting the results from takeout you may have wiped your Google history. When you're deleting browsing data, note the message at the bottom of the window:
[image]

Unless you sign out of Chrome first, any deletion will be run on your entire Google account, not just the one installation of your browser.

Comment: I'll try this but I'm not looking for looking history, I'm looking for browser history - as in websites I used. Is there a way to get that from the location history?

Comment: My bad - Yes, you can export browser history with Takeout - just select that option on the Takeout screen.

Comment: I did that and it was only for the last 8 days like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: In that case, you likely deleted your browser history from Google's servers. If you were signed into Chrome and went to clear your browser history, it's now the default behavior for it to be wiped from your Google account. You have to sign out of Chrome first before cleaning history to keep it in your account.

Comment: I did NOT delete my history, I merely deleted my cache. And as I mentioned in the question, I am able to see the history of the browser but not in one go I have to scroll down in order to be able to search it so it is definitely not deleted.

Comment: Are you logged into the Chrome browser? Can you post a screenshot of where you're seeing the history in your browser but not in the Takeout export?

Comment: yes, I am logged in, I will update the question. you are right deleting the cache seems to have deleted the history in my activity as well why is that?

Comment: if you update your answer to what you wrote in the comments I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with how this could have happened.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, and it turned out that the browser history is simply split into multiple files. From what I can tell, there are three places to look within the folder downloaded from takeout:

1. Chrome/BrowserHistory.json
2. 'My Activity'/Search/MyActivity.json
3. 'My Activity'/Chrome/MyActivity.json

Did you use file number 1? I started off using just this one and found lots of stiff to be missing.
I have no idea what the difference between numbers 1 and 3 is, but I'm guessing that files 1 and 3 ones show only sites visited using Chrome, while file 2 includes searches made in all browsers. I haven't yet compared the contents of each file, but will update my answer with any differences I find.